# Update table using inner join with subquery

Tags: t-sql, subquery

I've searched the web and have been unable to come up with a solution. I appreciate any help given.

I've got a table with these values, among others.

```
Item Charge No  Item Ledger Entry No    IsReceivedInFull
--------------------------------------------------------
Ocean Freight   1525593
Factory Cost    1525593
Overhead        1525593
Factory Cost    1525593
Fee             1525593
Duty            1525593
Landing Freight 1525593
```

I'm trying to loop through my results to check that for each Item Ledger Entry No I've got these five components in my table; 'Ocean Freight', 'Factory Cost', 'Fee', 'Duty', and 'Landing Freight'. If an individual Item Ledger Entry No has atleast five rows, one for each of the above mentioned Item Charge No's then I'd like to set 'IsReceivedInFull' to "Yes"

I come from an ABAP programming background and know this would be easily done with a couple of LOOP statements but I'm new to T-SQL and have struggled to solve this simple problem. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Could you post any code that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
UPDATE mytable tgt
SET    tgt.isreceivedinfull="Yes"
WHERE  tgt.isreceivedinfull is null and
       exists(SELECT src.item_ledger_Entry_no, count(*) 
              FROM   mytable src
              WHERE  src.item_ledger_entry_no = tgt.item_ledger_entry_no  
                     and src.item_charge_no in ("Ocean Freight", 
                                                "Factory Cost", 
                                                "Fee", 
                                                "Duty", 
                                                "Landing Freight")
                    group by src.item_ledger_entry_no
                    having count(*) >= 5)
```

You may have to adapt the string literal(" or ')depending on your type of DB, and the field names ad table name as they are not available from your example.

That should work.

For explanation : The exists condition will be true if the result of the sub-select is a non null record set (means more that one row). By using the tgt.item_ledger_entry_no in the where clause of the sub-select, you will only get non null if this particular item has the 5 entries you are looking for.
Saying this, it will also set a "Yes" to all rows with same ID but one of the litteral not in your list (named "Overhead"). And because you have duplicated rows (named "Factory Cost" is there twice), the having condition is set to greater or equal.

Hope that helps

Daniel